# Error ClassCastException: java.net.Socket can not be cast to javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket in the getPage method of the WebClient object (HtmlUnit)

Tags: java, htmlunit

I found the following error when trying to use the getPage method of the HtmlUnit WebClient object:

**java.lang.ClassCastException: java.net.Socket cannot be cast to javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket**

My Code:

```
        BrowserVersion firefox17WithUptoDateFlash = new BrowserVersion(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_17.getApplicationName(),
            BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_17.getApplicationVersion(), BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_17.getUserAgent(),
            BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_17.getBrowserVersionNumeric(),
            new BrowserVersionFeatures[] { BrowserVersionFeatures.JS_FRAME_RESOLVE_URL_WITH_PARENT_WINDOW,
                    BrowserVersionFeatures.STYLESHEET_HREF_EXPANDURL,
                    BrowserVersionFeatures.STYLESHEET_HREF_STYLE_NULL });

    PluginConfiguration plugin = new PluginConfiguration("Shockwave Flash", "Shockwave Flash 14.0 r0",
            "NPSWF32_14_0_0_145.dll");
    plugin.getMimeTypes()
            .add(new PluginConfiguration.MimeType("application/x-shockwave-flash", "Adobe Flash movie", "swf"));

    firefox17WithUptoDateFlash.getPlugins().add(plugin);

    webClient = new WebClient(firefox17WithUptoDateFlash);
    webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
    webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);


    // Get the first page
    final HtmlPage page1 = webClient.getPage("https://www.example.com/login.html");
```

Note 1: I am trying to execute this code from an Action in Struts.

Note 2: To put it here in the stack, I changed the url. But I'm trying to access a page login using https.

Stack Trace:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.net.Socket cannot be cast to javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.HtmlUnitSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(HtmlUnitSSLSocketFactory.java:116)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:168)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:326)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:610)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:445)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:835)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:72)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.HttpWebConnection.getResponse(HttpWebConnection.java:167)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseFromWebConnection(WebClient.java:1281)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponse(WebClient.java:1198)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:307)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:376)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:361)
at br.com.yyyyy.xxxxx.integracao.LeitorAtendimento.<init>(LeitorAtendimento.java:58)
at br.com.yyyyy.xxxxx.action.caldario.obrig.AbrirAct.executar(AbrirAct.java:122)
at br.com.yyyyy.xxxxx.action.AjaxAction.execute(AjaxAction.java:61)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:431)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:236)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:414)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.ajaxanywhere.AAFilter.doFilter(AAFilter.java:46)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:670)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I would just like to solve this. Can someone help me?

Comment: Please post your stack trace

Comment: @RBRi Here's my stacktrace.

Comment: Please make sure you have the correct version of httpclient (and only one) in your classpath.

Comment: Thank you for your help @RBRi. I updated the version of htmlunit to the most current one. Just like the other dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error has been resolved while updating the project dependencies.

Comment: Ran into this issue because Google referenced the version 2.13 as the #1 result when looking for the HtmlUnit maven package. I c/c the mvnrepository snippet as usual without noticing it wasn't the last version. Your post & answer helped look in the right direction :)